# Double UINavigationBar in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

We have a `UINavigationViewController` as root `viewController` in `AppDelegate`:

```
 Restore *callRestore=[[Restore alloc]initWithNibName:@"Restore" bundle:nil];
 self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:callRestore];
 self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

We are pushing a new `viewController` (`TabViewController`) from above Restore:

```
 callTabView=[[TabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:callTabView animated:YES];
```

In this `TabViewController` we are adding `UITabBarController` programatically as subview and in this `UITabBarController` we have 5 `UINavigationBarController` as view controllers:

```
NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navControllerDashboard, navControllerAccounts, navControllerTransation,navControllerCallDisplayReports,navControllerMore, nil];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.tabBarController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

When we are rotating any view from these 5 `UINavigationViewController` we are getting 2 `UINavigationBar` on top in both `landscape` and `portrait` mode.

Check below image.

[image]

[image]

and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation is not calling from these 5 UINavigationViewController view.

Any help?

Comment: callTabView is UIViewController. We are initialising tabBarController and  adding tabBarController like this:    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; [self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a view controller to another one as a subview manually you have to do the following:

```
UIViewController *parent = ...;
UIViewController *child = ...;

[child willMoveToParentViewController: parent];
[parent addChildViewController: child];
[parent.view addSubview: child.view];
[child didMoveToParentViewController:parent];
```

This will propagate all the events to the child view controller and possibly remove unexpected behaviour.